# iMacro Regex issue

Tags: regex

I'm having an issue with Regex as we speak.
I want to click an unfollow button on Tumblr, yet the unfollow buttons are all different.
This requires me to use regex of course, so I'm wondering how I can do this the most efficient way. The unfollow button looks like this: "unfollow_button_{USERNAME}"

I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you just use `unfollow_button_*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `unfollow_button_.*`. The wildcard is usually enough unless you use a SEARCH command with a Regex option to return submatches.